# OpenGL: Objects are smooth if normally drawn, but edged when rendering to FBO

Tags: opengl, fbo

I have a problem with different visual results when using a FBO compared to the default framebuffer:

I render my OpenGL scene into a framebuffer object, because I use this for color picking. The thing is that if I render the scene directly to the default framebuffer, the output on the screen is quite smooth, meaning the edges of my objects look a bit like if they were anti-aliased. When I render the scene into the FBO and afterwards use the output to texture a quad that spans the whole viewport, the objects have very hard edges where you can easily see every single colored pixel that belongs to the objects.

Good:

[image: dtizcto7.png]

Bad:

[image: wy7hg754.png]

At the moment I have no idea what the reason for this could be. I am not using some kind of anti-aliasing.

System:
Fedora 18 x64
Intel HD Graphics 4000 and Nvidia GT 740M (same result)

**Edit1:**

As stated by Damon and Steven Lu, there is probably some kind of anti-aliasing enabled by the system by default. I couldn't figure out so far how to disable this feature.
The thing is that I was just curious why this setting only had an effect on the default framebuffer and not the one handled by the FBO. To get anti-aliased edges for the FBO too, I will probably have to implement my own AA method.

Comment: This looks perfectly normal. You have probably enabled MSAA in the grasphic card's control panel (some setting like "override application" or "force always on"), which is why the render-to-screen looks antialiased. Rendering to a FBO does not use multisampling, unless you explicitly tell OpenGL to do so by adding multisample attachments.

Comment: @Damon: Answers. Post *answers*, not comments.

Comment: What's wrong with posting a comment? If you're so certain his comment is accurate and answers the question completely, post it yourself.

Comment: @Damon: Thx, I thought of that too, but I the Intel Graphics relies on Mesa and the Nvidia card brings its own OpenGL implementation as far as I know. The consequence would be that this should effect only one of them.  
Edit: Is there a way to check whether AA is enabled or not?

Comment: It must then be some setting your program or environment sets that enables AA on the frame buffer.

Comment: Also notice how the shade of the background and cube are different. Gamma correction/sRGB conversion issues?

Comment: @Steven Lu:  
I fixed the shading issue. There was an error in my fragment shader which did one calculation twice.

Comment: Are you still unable to isolate the reason why non-FBO rendering is anti-aliased? Check anything render target related, anything in the drivers.

Comment: I was searching for a while but couldn't find something usefull. The Intel driver seems to have nothing to tweak at all and the Nvidia driver is a bit buggy because of my attempt to use Linux and Nvidia Optimus together. That the scene is anti-aliased as default is not that problematic. I just thought it would be nice to have the FBO anti-aliased too. I'm working on this now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you draw your scene into custom FBO the externally defined MSAA level doesn't apply anymore.You must configure your FBO to have Multi-sample texture or render buffer attachments setting number of sample levels along the way.[Here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples#MSAA) is a reference.